# The program prints the statement every time the condition in the loop is correct

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I am trying to have the user input their grades and if the grades are above 90 to print them in one row, below 65 print them in one row, and if between 65 and 90 print them in one row. However, say every time there is a grade above 90, it will print "above 90" and then grade for each grade when I only want it to print the statement once. I understand I have that inside the condition so it will print it every time the condition is met, but where would I put that line of code so that this problem does not occur.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class StudentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many courses did you take during the school year? : ");
        int takeCoursesNum = sc.nextInt();

        int grades[] = new int[takeCoursesNum]; // array number start "0" ~ ex) { [0], [1], [2] }

        for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter your grade for that course : ");
            int grade = sc.nextInt();
            grades[i] = grade;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
            if (grades[i] < 65) {
                System.out.println("\nGrades below 65 : " + grades[i]);// System.out.println : auto change line. no need \n.
            }

            if (grades[i] > 90) {
                System.out.println("Grades above 90 : " + grades[i]);
            }

            if (grades[i] > 65 && grades[i]<90) {
                System.out.println("Grades between 65 and 90: " + grades[i]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add expected output and actual output.

Comment: When you run the program what output you are expecting? and that the output you are getting?

Comment: Right now I am getting 
Grades above 90 : 100
Grades between 65 and 90: 80
Grades between 65 and 90: 70
Grades below 65 : 60

Comment: The expected output is 
Grades between 65 and 90: x,y,z
Grades below 65: x,y,z
Grades above 90: x,y,z

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop the array three separate times also have the label (`"Grades below 65"`) out of the loop so it will print the statement only once. Finally use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` so the grades will be printed in the same line.

```
System.out.print("\nGrades below 65 : ");
for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
    if (grades[i] < 65) {
        System.out.print(grades[i]);
    }
}

System.out.print("\nGrades below 90 : ");
for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
    if (grades[i] > 90) {
        System.out.print(grades[i]);
    }
}

System.out.print("\nGrades between 65 and 90: ");
for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
    if (grades[i] > 65 && grades[i]<90) {
        System.out.print(grades[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello user11833872!

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many courses did you take during the school year? : ");
    int takeCoursesNum = sc.nextInt();

    int grades[] = new int[takeCoursesNum]; // array number start "0" ~ ex) { [0], [1], [2] }

    for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter your grade for that course : ");
        int grade = sc.nextInt();
        grades[i] = grade;
    }

    System.out.println("below 65 : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
        if (grades[i] < 65) {
            System.out.print(i+", ");// System.out.println : auto change line. no need \n.
        }
    }

    System.out.println("above 90 : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < takeCoursesNum; i++) {
        if (grades[i] > 90) {
            System.out.print(i+", ");
        }
    }
```

i change it. i hope this is what you want. :)